# SSIS - export from SQL table to multiple flat files based on first column values

Tags: sql, dynamic, foreach, ssis, export

Here is an example of what the SQL Table looks like:

```
Name    Class   Grade
Jesse   English A
Jesse   Math    C
Jesse   History A
Scott   Math    B
Scott   History B
Scott   English A
Mike    History A
Mike    English D
```

I am trying to get SSIS to dynamically create a flat file for each person. Example:

Flat File name: **Jesse**

```
Name    Class   Grade
Jesse   English A
Jesse   Math    C
Jesse   History A
```

Flat File name: **Scott**

```
Name    Class   Grade
Scott   Math    B
Scott   History B
Scott   English A
```

Flat File name: **Mike**

```
Name    Class   Grade
Mike    History A
Mike    English D
```

I can easily create a static link between the sql table and the flat file but I plan on adding a lot of people to the table which would otherwise cause me to create a data flow task for each.  This would not be ideal.  I was hoping for a for each loop that identified the distinct values within the Name column and then output the qualified rows into a flat file.

Answer (score 4):

This is how your package should look like :

[image: in the control flow]

[image: in the data flow]

right click->variable 1.student-->object
                      2.students-->string(for holding all names of students giving you required) result

In the data flow -- connection managers--right click-- flat file connection-->properties-->expression mention it as something like this ::`"C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\ssis_stuff_from_stackoverflow\\citys.txt-"+ @[User::student] +".txt"`

the package succesfully executes affecting 3 rows and adding 3 flat files in the `folder 
path`

[here is one good example](http://simonlv.blogspot.in/2012/05/ssis-step-by-step-001-load-data-from.html)

Comment: The link is broken but here is good example: https://blog.pragmaticworks.com/looping-through-a-result-set-with-the-foreach-loop

Answer (score 2):

First run a query to find a recordset of unique students:

```
select distinct name from myTable
```

Then use the foreach loop to loop though and run the following parameterized query:

```
SELECT class, grade 
FROM myTable 
WHERE name = ?
```

Use a derived column to include the name to the resultset.

Put this in a flat file destination. The connectionstring for the output file will be dynamic.

These are the steps. If you get stuck, there are plenty of examples online, or feel free to ask.